# Проблемы с Javascript и картой изображения

Tags: javascript, html

Привет. У меня есть небольшая [страничка с прибором](http://gtp4all.ru/voltmeter/), по элементам прибора можно потыкать, понажимать, но иногда бывают проблемы с javascript и картой изображения. Я думаю, что проблемы как-то связаны с кэшем. Иногда все работает, все элементы прибора нажимаются, но иногда "успевает" загрузится только карта изображения - курсор "pointer" на элементах прибора это подтверждает. Но, тогда javascript не выполняет свои функции. Потом чистишь кэш в браузере и перезагружаешь страницу и получается, что даже карты изображения нет, только изображение прибора. Потом еще раз чистишь кэш и перезагружаешься, тогда опять снова все работает. В чем проблема?

Причем на локалке все работает отлично постоянно

P.S. Браузер Mozilla Firefox

Comment: ещё живы эти??? им же за 30...а прибор классный!
При выключении питания - лампочки продолжают гореть :)

Comment: Какой браузер у Вас)?

Comment: мозилла,хром
лампочки включаются и при выключенном питании :)
ошибки, как у тебя хорошо ловятся в отладчиках (хром, мозилла)

Comment: @Вадим А, Вы вон про какие лампочки говорите. Прибор пока работает независимо, все и везде можно нажимать безнаказанно

Comment: светодиоды над кнопками, я думал что логика уже прописана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь отладчиком!

Лично у меня ваш сайт падает на вызове

```
if (element.contains("button")) { ...
```

где `element` - это строка. В JS у строк [(пока)](http://ericleads.com/2013/10/javascript-string-contains/) нет метода `contains`. Вместо него стоит использовать `indexOf`:

```
if (element.indexOf("button") > -1) { ...
```

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Однако в Mozilla Firefox на этом вызове сайт не падал. Но я поменял contains на indexOf, теперь в Opera например на этом вызове не падает. Но проблема все равно осталась. Уточню: Чистим кэш, перезагружаемся = не работает, перезагружаемся = работает. Опять чистим кэш, перезагружаемся = не работает.

Comment: воспользуйтесь отладчиком. в моем хроме работает :)

Comment: InternetExplorer, Opera, Chrome - везде работает, кроме Firefox, причем в приватном окне Firefox работает все отлично, а вот когда в обычном окне после очистки кэша map area отсутствует. Даже не знаю как это отладить =)

Comment: поставить firebug?

Comment: Починил. Изображение прибора в зависимости от разрешения экрана увеличивается, любо уменьшается. Поскольку карта изображения строилась по полно масштабному изображению, была в одном из скриптов функция, которая корректировала координаты карты изображения. Функция уже выполнялась, пока изображение только еще начиналось грузиться, следовательно разрешение у него было 0х0, вот и координаты карты были все нулевые.